# Angular 1.5 passing a function with parameters to a component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a session service like follows with two methods representing two ways of authenticating:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .service('sessionService', SessionService);

function SessionService() {
  var $ctrl = this;

  this.logInTypeA = function(username, password, authenticator) {
    ...
  }

  this.logInTypeB = function(username, password, authenticator) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

I have a log in form component.  I would like to have two instances of the form which use the two different log in methods but are otherwise the same:

```
<log-in-form log-in-method="$ctrl.sessionSerive.logInTypeA"></log-in-form>
<log-in-form log-in-method="$ctrl.sessionSerive.logInTypeB"></log-in-form>
```

The component's JS looks something like this:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .component('logInForm', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/log-in-form.template.html',
    controller: LogInFormController,
    bindings: {
      logInMethod: '&'
    }
  });

function LogInFormController() {
  var $ctrl = this;

  this.username = '';
  this.password = '';
  this.authenticator = '';

  this.logIn = function() {
    $ctrl.logInMethod($ctrl.username, $ctrl.password, $ctrl.authenticator);
  };

  ...
}
```

However, I get an error when I try to run this:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$ctrl' in testloginemail@example.com
```

How do I pass a method in a service to a component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML has a typo in the name of the service. Here is how I do this in Angular 1.4.x.

In the HTML, you should add the parameters of the function being called:

```
<log-in-form log-in-method="$ctrl.sessionService.logInTypeA(username, password, authenticator)"></log-in-form>
<log-in-form log-in-method="$ctrl.sessionService.logInTypeB(username, password, authenticator)"></log-in-form>
```

For the component, you need to add curly braces around the parameters and add each parameter name:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .component('logInForm', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/log-in-form.template.html',
    controller: LogInFormController,
    bindings: {
      logInMethod: '&'
    }
  });

function LogInFormController() {
  var $ctrl = this;

  this.username = '';
  this.password = '';
  this.authenticator = '';

  this.logIn = function() {
    $ctrl.logInMethod({username: $ctrl.username,
                       password: $ctrl.password,
                       authenticator: $ctrl.authenticator});
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh wow.  I'm facepalming at my typo.  But that wasn't my only mistake!  Thank you so much for explaining the bit about the parameters in the brackets, too.  Great, clear answer.

Comment: @carmenism No worries, my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to use service functions by name:

```
<log-in-form log-in-method="logInTypeA"></log-in-form>
<log-in-form log-in-method="logInTypeB"></log-in-form>
```

Use attribute `@` binding, and inject the service in the component:

```
app.component('logInForm', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/log-in-form.template.html',
    controller: LogInFormController,
    bindings: {
      logInMethod: '@'
    }
});

function LogInFormController(sessionService) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  this.username = '';
  this.password = '';
  this.authenticator = '';

  this.logIn = function() {
    var method = sessionService[$ctrl.logInMethod];
    method($ctrl.username, $ctrl.password, $ctrl.authenticator);
  };

  ...
}
```

Use [property accessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to select the desired service method by name.